# Android application for London Transport (usability ?)

Tags: iphone, android, usability, ios, usability-testing

I'm developing the Android application for London Transport which includes Journey Planner, Tube status, Live Departures Boards, Maps, Finding a taxi function and so on.

I'd like to get some feedback about the layout of the application, because it is one of essential part of developing. Therefore, I made a basic prototype of the application that you can find here --> http://appas.co.cc/App/

Comment: Hi Tom, welcome to UX.SE! Unfortunately we don't accept general questions asking for feedback (see the [FAQ](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)). Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Looks good. The only problem is 'Home' button. It's unclear for the first launch if it leads to home screen, or 'planning journey home'.